# Contact form & IE8 woes - can't seem to stop the form submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, return-value, preventdefault

I have a contact form that is submitted using the `.ajax()` method in jQuery in order to submit the form without the page refreshing. It works in all browsers except IE, which is throwing a hissy fit and is adamant on refreshing the page.

This is my code:

```
function appointmentform() {    
    $("#appointment-form").on("submit", function(e) {

        // serialize all input data
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(dataString);

        // if there are no inputs with errors
        if ($("input.required.error").length < 1) {

            // ajax call to mail.php script
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.thesalonleamingtonspa.com/mail",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    // success notice
                }
            });

        }

        // cancel form submit
        if (e.preventDefault) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        } else { 
            e.returnValue = false; 
        }
    });
}
```

I realize that `e.preventDefault()` means nothing to IE, but I thought `e.returnValue = false` was the equivalent. Anybody know why it's not working for me?

Edit: It's just IE8 that's the problem child.

Comment: I would write the form tag like `<form ... onsubmit="return false"></form>`

Comment: I never had any trouble using jQuery's `preventDefault()` with IE 8.

Comment: @inhan, he's using jQuery, so inline JavaScript is ugly and unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The real culprit was IE8 & `console.log`**

IE8 doesn't support writing to `console` straight out of the box, so the script stops running as soon as the `console` function is encountered. In my code, `preventDefault` came after the `console` part, so it did not run.

**The solution:** Keeping the Developer Tools open in IE8 will allow you to write to `console`

I am responding to my own question because none of the other answers were 100% correct, although they were helpful. Anybody who views my question in the future may benefit from hearing the real reason that I have now outlined.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `false` should cancel form submit

Instead of

```
    if (e.preventDefault) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    } else { 
        e.returnValue = false; 
    }
```

Use

```
return false;
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: instead of using a submit, just use a button:

```
// use this ~ buttons don't do anything unless explicitly told to
<input type="button">

// not this ~ the default behavior is to submit ~ which you don't want
<input type="submit">
```

You just need to listen for the click of the button and then fire the function.

I haven't used a submit button in years ...literally... just to avoid this issue.

The way I normally listen for a "submit" event is on click. In my experience, even IE can handle click events.

```
function doAjaxStuff {
    // do form validation
    // do ajax stuff
}
myButton.click(doAjaxStuff);
```

Comment: Not bad, that actually was a great idea. That stopped the refresh, but the contact form is still not sending successfully from IE8. Seems to cause an error at the `console.log`. Would that error stop the code written after `console` to not execute?

Answer (score 1):

> I realize that e.preventDefault() means nothing to IE

That's only true if you're not using jQuery. jQuery makes this cross-browser.

Guess: do you use jQuery < 1.4?

> The JavaScript submit event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. However, scripts that rely on event delegation with the submit event will work consistently across browsers as of jQuery 1.4, which has normalized the event's behavior.

-- http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I totally agree with this, but it's not really an answer to his question and should have been posted as a comment instead.

Comment: Interesting. Well, I'm using the latest jQuery. I have fixed the refresh issue using a button type input, instead of submit. However, the rest of the code fails and the `console.log` throws up a script error in IE. :(

Comment: @muppethead... you mentioned it twice already... what is the exact error message?

Comment: @Sparky672 - I really don't know. IE8 displays the yellow warning sign in the bottom left hand corner. When I double click that, it informs me that "console" on line 205 is the problem. No emails are sent, so does that mean all the code after the console.log does not run (because the code that makes the contact form run comes after the console part) ? I really need to know that in order to diagnose properly. Does a script error on one line stop the rest of the code from running?

Comment: @muppethead, it simply means that line 205 is the problem, but there should be an error message there too.  What exactly is on line 205?

Comment: @muppethead, so what happens when you just remove line 205?  Maybe some invisible characters are messing up that line.

Comment: @Sparky672 line 205 has `console.log(dataString);` - I'll try removing all console.logs throughout the script and see what happens.

Comment: @Sparky672 - removing all instances of `console.log` fixed the entire shindig. I guess I can't use console.log with ie8

Comment: @muppethead, there is no issue with `console.log` and IE 8, AFAIK... maybe you had stray invisibles on those lines (copy & paste from online?).  Maybe the data exceeded some length limit.  Try some things and see.

Comment: @Sparky672 - No, there really is a problem there with IE8. "IE8 has a console but your scripts can’t call console.log() directly" Source: http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/ - Anyway, thanks a bunch for your help in solving this matter. I'm limited in my ability to express gratitude, so I'll just upvote you as much as I can.

Comment: @muppethead, I appreciate it, but up-voting comments is just for the benefit of the reader; they don't count towards any reputation or scores.